# Ubuntu Dash not showing software results and Software Center freezing / not bringing up gksu prompt

Tags: 12.04, gnome, software-center, unity-dash, gksu

I posted a video to Youtube, and I think the youtube description and/or video (a short desktop recording with me speaking) pretty much sum it up.

http://youtu.be/EAnzrE1rqRs

[description on video]

I just wanted to post this to the askubuntu.com forums.  This is for an up to date Ubuntu 12.04 ("Precise Pangolin") installed on a laptop.  If anyone has an idea why either the software center will freeze when launching, or why the dash (or even alt-f2) can't find installed software like gnome-terminal, gedit, or firefox when I type it, I am interested to hear your comments.

[/end description]

Thank you for your time. :)

Edit: I noticed these problems around the same time so I have reason to suspect they are related.  And I'll admit, the way I like to roll is with a root prompt - by using "sudo bash", entering my password, and running admin commands to do things that you need the prompt for.  I dislike entering my password many times, and I do things that are appropriate for standard user privileges in another tab most of the time anyway.  But Software Center freezing on me and nothing coming up on the dash when I hit the button with an Ubuntu logo on it and type a program's name is a slight inconvenience which less knowledgeable users may (either never encounter) or find it impossible to work around.  I tried searching for a solution with Google for a while but didn't come up with much.

Answer (score 1):

I found another thread with the issue of the `dash` and I've also been having the same problem with software centre as well.  Some solutions for these problems are discussed in detail [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1894351).

One suggestion on that link worked for me, and for that I entered in the terminal:

```
sudo unity --reset-icons
```

Good luck.

Comment: [That forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1894351) doesn't contain the suggestion to run `unity --reset-icons` as `root` with `sudo`. Did you run it with `sudo`? This seems like a bad idea, for [this reason](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo), and because it's the non-`root` user's icon configuration that needs to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

Related? [Thread 12289173 in UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12289173)

I can temporarily fix software center with  `rm -r ~/.cache/software-center`